# Is HarmonyOS JS UI framework similar to React-Native UI framework?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

Will the development of HarmonyOS JS affect its performance? Is it similar to the operating principle of UI frameworks like React-Native?

Answer (score 2):

The principle of HarmonyOS JS is different from React-Native. The bottom layer is a set of UI self-rendering frameworks, which can be cross-platform. For example, the preview effect on the PC is the same rendering path as watch or TV, and the effect is the same. In terms of performance, the current performance of some typical scenes such as gallery, e-commerce, a long list can basically reach full frames. However, due to the performance limitations of the JS language itself, complicated JS logic operations are not recommended. HarmonyOS will continue to optimize the overall performance, please continue to pay attention.